# Get all list elements in prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I need to get all list element in out side of the list using prolog.
`['1','2','3',a,b,c]` to become `X='1','2','3',a,b,c`
I need the result X as shown above.

is it possibile to get the result?

Comment: Huh? You want multiple values unified with single variable but not a list? How is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will literally display what you're asking for (I'm assuming you're interested in the result strictly for display purposes).

```
print_list(L) :-
    write('X='),
    print_list_aux(L), !.

print_list_aux([H1,H2|T]) :-
    print(H1),
    write(','),
    print_list_aux([H2|T]).
print_list_aux([X]) :-
    print(X),
    nl.
print_list_aux([]) :- nl.
```

Example:

```
?- print_list(['1', '2', a, b]).
X='1','2',a,b
true.

?-
```

If you use `write/1` instead of `print/1`, you eliminate the quotes on the numbers in the output, so it would be: `X=1,2,a,b`.

Comment: Thankyou for your answer.It is posible to only for the printing purpose

Comment: @Gamsh technically any time you write a data item out for the user to see, it is for display purposes. However, in Prolog, the more natural representation of a list is with the brackets. So if you say `X = ['1', '2', a, b]), write(X).` you would get `[1,2,a,b]`  for the `write` output and you wouldn't need any special code to get it.